pip3 tries to write to /var/log even with venv and failing
I follow these steps, and they always fail.
mkdir python-mess
cd python-mess
echo toml > requirements.txt
which python3
# /usr/bin/python3
which pip3
# /usr/bin/pip3
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
# (.venv is added to prompt)
which pip3
# /home/karel.bilek/python-mess/.venv/bin/pip3
which python3
# /home/karel.bilek/python-mess/.venv/bin/python3
pip3 install -r requirements.txt


The last step always fails, with
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/python_pip.log'
WHY? What else to do?
I am using Debian Bookworm, plain python 3, plain bash. I am not installing something weird, just toml package! There is nothing else in the folder except for requirements.txt.

It seems the issue was global /etc/pip.conf that had
[global]
log-file = /var/log/python_pip.log

I solved it by doing
mkdir -p ~/.pip
echo "[global]" > ~/.pip/pip.conf
echo "log = ~/.pip/pip.log" >> ~/.pip/pip.conf


(This was recommended to me by ChatGPT, but it worked, so I hope it's allowed here.)

I'd be very much intereted who has put the file there. It's not in my Debian. Any output from dpkg-query --no-pager --search /etc/pip.conf ? If not — I recommend to remove the file: sudo rm /etc/pip.conf

@phd it was put there by the manager of the machine. it's not a personal machine, it's a managed machine with more tenants. I don't even have rights to remove it.

I see, thanks!..
